# Why doesn't Javascript Dynamic HTML5 Table Not Appear on Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to take quantities of products and multiplying them by the price before inserting these constantly updating values into an HTML table. I am using a forever loop to constantly take input for the sake of the example.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
<!--
var product1 = 0;
var product2 = 0;
var product3 = 0;
var product4 = 0;
var product5 = 0;
var productNum = 0;
var productNumInt = 0;
var quantitySold = 0;
var quantitySoldInt = 0;

document.write("<table>");
document.write("<tr><th>Product Number</th><th>Quantity Sold</th></tr>");
document.write("<tr><td>1</td><td>$" + product1 + "</td></tr>");
document.write("<tr><td>2</td><td>$" + product2 + "</td></tr>");
document.write("<tr><td>3</td><td>$" + product3 + "</td></tr>");
document.write("<tr><td>4</td><td>$" + product4 + "</td></tr>");
document.write("<tr><td>5</td><td>$" + product5 + "</td></tr>");
document.write("</table>");

while (true) {
  productNum = window.prompt("Please enter the product number");
  quantitySold = window.prompt("Please enter the quantity sold");
  productNumInt = parseInt(productNum);
  quantitySoldInt = parseInt(quantitySold);

  switch (productNumInt) {
    case 1:
      product1 += quantitySoldInt * 2.98;
      break;
    case 2:
      product2 += quantitySoldInt * 4.50;
      break;
    case 3:
      product3 += quantitySoldInt * 9.98;
      break;
    case 4:
      product4 += quantitySoldInt * 4.49;
      break;
    case 5:
      product5 += quantitySoldInt * 6.87;
      break;
  }
}
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @vZ10 you need to put the script in the end of the `body` tag. Also you're prompting user to fill a data after actual render of a table(`document.write` calls). Try to place  `document.write` calls after prompt

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to `document.write` this part:

```
document.write("<table>");
document.write("<tr><th>Product Number</th><th>Quantity Sold</th></tr>");
```

In fact, you don't need to use `document.write` at all in your situation and it can be healthier to avoid it when not necessary.

You could relieve some pain by having this markup as a base model:

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr><th>Product Number</th><th>Quantity Sold</th></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td><td id="product1"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td><td id="product2"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td><td id="product3"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>4</td><td id="product4"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>5</td><td id="product5"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then, you can access your fields with something like this (the script being at the end of the body, or at least after the table markup):

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("product1").innerHTML = "1.00";
document.getElementById("product2").innerHTML = "2.00";
document.getElementById("product3").innerHTML = "3.00";
document.getElementById("product4").innerHTML = "4.00";
document.getElementById("product5").innerHTML = "5.00";
```

Even better, you can create a DOM (Document Object Model) text element and update it (see [DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)):

```
var product1_text = document.createTextNode("1.00");
document.getElementById("product1").appendChild(product1_text);

// now you can update the value
product1_text.textContent = "1.50"; // calculated value
```

I will let you think about the problem of calculating with text cells. With your current script, you will face issues with operator += on a string. Keep in mind that when you get a displayed number, you work with a string and not the base 10 number represented by it. You will need the function `parseFloat(stringValue)` to achieve that.

I hope this helped and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your script at the end of the body. Now it runs before your page appear on the screen.

Comment: Now it runs before the DOM has builded!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write script after your `<body>` tag ends i.e. after `</body>`.